# How to detect Android 4.0 native browser?

Tags: user-agent

Default user agent on Android v4 is :

> Mozzila/5.0 (x11;linux x86_64) Applewebkit/534.24(KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/11.0.696.34 Safari/534.24

How to detect it with php, but only on mobile devices?

Comment: Better question... What feature are you trying to detect support for?... Usually detecting the feature through JavaScript is much better.

Comment: I'd like to include one js file only for smartphones.

Comment: You could sniff the user agent for the keywords "mobile" and "tablet" but it would be a weak match as some IE desktop browsers include "tablet" in their UA. Though I think feature sniffing would still make more sense... Unless you are sniffing to find out if an android phone to present a link to download an android app... Hmm then again I noticed that UA you posted doesn't include mobile, tablet, google, or android... Hmm...